# Funcion split() en python

Tags: python, string, split

Mi pregunta es si al usar split() en un string este me lo separa palabra por palabra y lo convierte  automaticamente en lista? por ejemplo

```
txt = input("introduzca texto:") # el string
textoSeparado=txt.split()
print(textoSeparado)
```

Tenia la confusion por un ejercicio, que quiero insertar el string separado palabra por palabra a una lista y me salia doble [[]]

Comment: Al ejecutar tu código, obtienes una lista de strings.

Comment: `split()` te retorna una lista, por defecto te lo separa por espacios

Comment: Para referencia de instrucciones, mirar la documentación: [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 1):

Para este tipo de preguntas te recomiendo primero buscar la documentación del método o clase con el que tienes dudas. En este caso, como podemos revisar en la documentación del método [`str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=- 1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> Devuelve una lista de las palabras de la cadena, utilizando sep como
> cadena delimitadora.

Como se detalla allí, al no especificar `sep`, se utiliza el espacio como delimitador.
Por lo tanto, lo que retornaría en tu caso es una lista de las palabras del string separadas por un espacio.

Si quieres saber más detalles, te invito a leer la [documentación completa.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)